# PHP MVC HTML fragment: generate new or use cached based on changes in app

Tags: php, model-view-controller, outputcache

I am making an MVC framework and have a question. 
What would be the best way to check if application has changed since last time cache was generated in order to decide whether to use cached fragment. E.g. on the home page let's say I have only 2 types of dynamic content: Blog posts and comments to posts. I have generated all partial fragments and cached them. Once there is a new post or new comment, I have to re-generate HTML. How would controller or view know that it has to be generated again?

Comment: this type of thing doesn't sound like it would be determined by the framework, but by the application code. there is no way that your framework could know the internals to check if cache needs to be generated. unless of course this framework has a very narrow scope, and can only be used for a specific type of app?

Comment: Yes it's a specific type of framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibly simple method would be to simply delete the cached content when a new post or comment is made; that way you know that you need to regenerate the HTML because it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. Simple but then you'd have to delete all possible cached fragments. For example if some page also has a small block "Latest comments" or "New blogs".

By the way in your scenario, which part of the app would have to make sure to delete cache? M, V or C?

Comment: Controller. Unfortunately, there's no real way to *entirely* avoid intermixing the layers just a little bit. You can avoid some of the penalties of it by moving the actual cache deletion code to the view (via an "invalidate" method or some such) and have the controller inform the view, but that's the only way I can think of.